# Software to autocomplete word like phrases express?

Tags: windows-7, autocomplete

Is there some software to autocomplete word like phrases express, when you type word that automatically give you some option to use word that have used before?
Program have to scan word that you already input and give you option to use it again, like in notepad++ (autocomplit).
For example: You want to open "Control panel" so you press "Win key" and start type "control", find control panel and click on them. So next time when you want to do same (open control panel) you again press "Win key" and start type "co" and that program in that moment give you option to use word "control" because you are already input it.
OS windows 7

Comment: Any reasons or requirements why you don't use Phrases Express? What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 7, i don't know how to configure it as well, ... have you some advice or link to some tuto, to make autocomlite to appear like in notepad++?

Comment: You increase your chance to get a useful answer if you *explain* what you want (not "like in [other application]" -- this just limits who might be able to help you to those familiar with the referenced program) in as proper English as you can manage (I'm not a native speaker, like many others here, and I find it difficult to tell what it is you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like http://www.autohotkey.com/ it can be setup to do virtually anything but there is an example of using it to do autocompletion, although you can program hotstrings to complete almost anything.

Comment: I finally find some autohotkey script  thnx man ...http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic53630.html&highlight=autocomplete+word

Answer (score 3):

Don't waste your time with PhraseExpander as there is a [free alternative to PhraseExpander](http://www.wordexpander.net).

**WordExpander is completely free.** No need to struggle with license keys and expensive upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

If You need launch programs. Check [launchy.net](http://www.launchy.net/).
If it crash in Win7 - disable controly plugin.