# "English autocompletion" program for Windows

Tags: productivity, autocomplete, typing

I never experimented with software which gives you "English autocompletion", but it sounds like something I'd love to use and that could make typing much much more efficient. I mean, if I start typing `eff` it's quite obvious I'm gonna write `efficient` so why not have auto-completion for that?

So I basically want a program that will give me "English autocompletion" on every program I use on my Windows computer.

Is anyone familiar with such a program?

Comment: There are other words besides 'efficient' that start with 'eff'. Effective, effervescent, efface, effeminate, etc... :)

Comment: I wouldn't use such a program. I have autocompletion on my phone and find it annoying even there. On a normal keyboard, it is much easier and even quicker to type word for word at moderate 35 WPM than to monitor when the program has finally chosen the correct word and hit the completion key (and if this is tab, I manage to hit caps lock instead ~5% of the cases). Also, if it isn't just your word processor, but a program which monitors any input, prepare for CLI commands, URLs and your personal passwords suddenly appearing in emails to your boss. This happens on my phone all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try TypingAid. It is an Autohotkey script that does the job fine.

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=53630

Answer (score 1):

Have a look a **[PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/)**.

> - Organize frequently used text snippets.
> - Expand abbreviations as you type.
> - Launch programs with text shortcuts.
> - **Auto-complete repetitive phrases (& words).**
> - Quick access to the Windows Clipboard History.
> - Correct spelling mistakes in any application.

Free for personal use, paid commercial version available.

[image]

See the [Feature List](http://www.phraseexpress.com/features.htm) for more information.

[image]

*Note: I am in no way, shape, or form affiliated with this product.*

Comment: Are you a user? If so I'd appreciate your personal opinion on the software.

Comment: I have not used it too much, as I do not have much need for it currently, @cool-RR, but it is a highly-configurable program and very powerful...A learning curve is involved but I think it is worth it...

Answer (score 0):

In this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/266360/software-to-autocomplete-word-like-phrases-express) I found an interesting answer, which might work just fine, it is a free alternative to PhrasesExpander, called [WordExpander](http://www.wordexpander.net)