# Autocompletion on all my programs for Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete

I'm looking for a tool to have an auto-completion feature (glory to zsh!)  working on my whole linux system.
It could be something similar to the suggestions given by the Android keyboard, but having a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> + something, for activating it.

[There's a question close to this one on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/269924/english-autocompletion-program-for-windows), but it's asking for Windows and English, I'd rather need one for Linux and Spanish. Also, the solutions presented there seem to be down for me.

If I can't find something for the whole system, an add-on for Firefox would be enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like [WordExpander](http://www.wordexpander.net) (or better :P)? but for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows you to manage collection of scripts and phrases, and assign abbreviations and hotkeys to these. This allows you to execute a script or insert text on demand in whatever program you are using.

[Autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) is a [best textexpander available](http://lifehacker.com/5845445/the-best-text-expansion-app-for-linux) for linux. It needs Python skills for the more advanced snippets.